# User story definition in spock

Tags: java, bdd, spock

I have recently started using the [spock framework](http://spockframework.org/) for BDD in my Java project.
I noticed that in a spock specification it is possible to define a feature and a given-when-then clause in a specification. For example:

```
MySpec extends Specification {

  //As a User I want the system to behave in some way

  def "it should provide feature 1"() {
    given: "some state"
    when : "some action"
    then : "some symptom"
  }

  def "it should provide feature 2"() {
    ...
  }
}
```

What I am missing is the user story part of the specification, the part that I put in a comment.

Is it possible in some way to write a spock specification that will provide the test output in the format:

```
+As a User I want the system to behave in some way
  +it should provide feature 1
    -given some state
    -when some action
    -then some symptom
  +it should provide feature 2
    -given some state
    -when some action
    -then some symptom
```

This is very similar to how [ScalaTest](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/tests_as_specifications) outputs its results.

I am basically missing that top level element that will allow me to easily group and display features. I would like to know if there is such a construct or if I do not understand the true nature of the spock framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new business report that's in the making for Spock 1.0 will support this feature via a `@Narrative` annotation attached to a spec class. To get a first impression, see [this sample spec](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/blob/groovy-1.8/spock-report/src/test/groovy/org/spockframework/report/sample/FightOrFlightStory.groovy) and the [resulting report](http://spockframework.github.io/spock/sampleReports/Ninja%20Commander.html).

Comment: awesome! that is precisely what I am looking for. will this code be available as a separate extension with the 1.0 release or will it be released independently?

Comment: It will be part of 1.0. An early version is already available in 1.0-SNAPSHOT, but it's not quite ready for general use.